# LINQ Count problems while trying to access to subList from a List of Objects (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, linq, oop, object

I'm having a pretty tough time figuring it out why it doesn't work properly but I'm asking for it.

```
    Dim goodCount As Integer = (From item In equipmentTagList
                                Where item.Importance = "Critique"
                                Where item.Status <> TargetRange.OutOfRange
                                Select item).Count()

    Dim badCount As Integer = (From item In equipmentTagList
                               Where item.Importance = "Critique"
                               Where item.Status.Contains(TargetRange.OutOfRange)
                               Select item).Count()
```

EquipmentTagList is a `List(Of MachineTag)` (custom object) so I want to get how many `MachineTag` from the EquipmentTagList matches the criteria. I'm still confused about why the first one works but not the other one. I know by debugging that the first one returns at least one result while the other returns nothing... I've searched a lot to get help for this error but unfortunately found nothing...

Thanks for helping me out.

**EDIT:**

The error I get is : 
System.InvalidOperationException with Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You can look at what kind of sql is generated from your linq statement. The difference is your .contains will expect your status to contain an Enum, converted as an integer. I would try passing in a list of enum TargetRange(list of ints) and do, myEnumList.Contains(Function(prop) prop.Status)

Comment: What is the type of `item.Status`?

Comment: currently its an integer refering to my custom enum which is as follows:
    `Public Enum TargetRange
        None
        Perfect
        BetweenMinMax
        OutOfRange
        Warning
    End Enum` so if Status = 0 it matches with TargetRange.None and so on

Comment: so .. `Where item.Status = TargetRange.OutOfRange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming for the moment that `item.Status` is an `Integer` data type (inferred from your use of `TargetRange.OutOfRange` as though it's an `Enum`), the syntax in your second snippet would be expected to fault.

The `.Contains()` method is reserved for use with `IEnumerable` objects, not `Integer` values.

If you modify your code slightly, to this:

```
Dim badCount = (From item In equipmentTagList
                    Where item.Importance = "Critique"
                    Where item.Status.Contains(TargetRange.OutOfRange)
                    Select item)
```

...and then set a breakpoint at some point after this call, you'll note that `badCount` is `Nothing`. Since `Nothing` can't have a `.Count`, the call fails.

Your first snippet is correct—as you've already pointed out.

**EDIT**

Something's not right here. Your code shouldn't even compile.

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

So `item.Status` certainly can't be an `Integer`.

Comment: @MikeDeshaies — Did you remove `.Count` as well?

Comment: By removing the .Count it was only giving me the IEnumerable Of MachineTag. And by trying to do a IsNot Nothing check it finds it as an empty IEnumerable.

Comment: supposedly `Status` is `Integer`, and you know that `.Contains` doesn't work on `Integer` and `Enum`, so I am a bit puzzled about leaving it in the code sample

Comment: Surprisingly the item.Status = TargetRange.OutOfRange works like a charm... Looks like it was too obvious in front of me that I couldn't see clearly the problem...

Comment: @InteXX strange enough that my Intellisense wasn't getting me any errors about it...

Comment: @MikeDeshaies you need `Option Strict` http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4022/option-strict/14043/how-to-switch-it-on

Comment: @Slai Thanks for the tip, this will greatly help improving myself as a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will make it a bit easier. You can group by `Status` after filtering by `Importance`:

```
Dim items = From i In equipmentTagList Where i.Importance = "Critique"
Dim counts = items.ToLookup(Function(i) i.Status <> TargetRange.OutOfRange)

Dim goodCount = counts(True).Count()
Dim badCount = counts(False).Count()
```